# Is hyperref's pdfborder option broken in TeX Live 2010?

Tags: hyperref, texlive

In TeX Live 2010, using `\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}` results in the warning

```
Package hyperref Warning: Invalid value `0 0 0'
(hyperref)                for option `pdfborder'.
(hyperref)                Option setting is ignored on input line 3790.
```

The same warning occurs using `\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0}`. Both of these are verbatim from the [`hyperref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) manual.

Comment: hyperref is changing so fast that "in TeXLive 2010" is not precise enough ;.). Heiko knows about the problem and it should be corrected in version  6.81o.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Ah great. I was wondering if the option had changed formats but the manual was out of date, or if it was a bug, or user error.

Comment: @Ulrike: That seems to me like it ought to be an answer eligible for voting and aceptance, rather than merely a helpful comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was fixed in the next version of `hyperref`. The solution is simply to update to a newer version. Currently v6.81q is the latest.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following line just before \endinput in your hyperref.cfg must fix the bug.
\providecommand*\@pdfborder{0 0 0}

This file was in directory texmf/tex/latex on my configuration.

I hope it will work for you too.