# Disabling the colored box surrounding links in hyperref

Tags: hyperref

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove ugly borders around clickable crossreferences and hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-crossreferences-and-hyperlinks)

I don't want that my links would have a colored box around them. Currently what I do is

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
```

or

```
\usepackage[pdfborder=0]{hyperref}
```

But both doesn't seem right.

How can I explicitly disable the colored box?

The manual implies that setting `pdfborder` to `0` is the correct way to do that, but maybe there's still a better way.

> The style of box around links;
>   defaults to a box with lines of 1pt
>   thickness, **but the `colorlinks` option
>   resets it to produce no border**.

But I still didn't see any explicit way to disable it.

Comment: According to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3146/is-hyperrefs-pdfborder-option-broken-in-tl-2010 there is a bug in certain versions, what version are you using?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/823/1235) answers your question. (Possible duplicate?)

Comment: Looks like a dupe to me

Comment: Grrr.. believe me I looked for similar answer. Sorry.